# Can My Flutter Mobile App Use My Google Apps Script?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-apps-script, google-authentication

My Flutter mobile app requires json input to populate its widgets (it simply needs to read/get the json data). I have a Google Apps Script deployed as Web App that generates json from my published Google Sheets spreadsheet. The Google Apps Script works flawlessly when i nav to its url from my web browser (logged in as script owner); but my Flutter app is not receiving the json data, presumably due to authentication.
Admittedly, I'm a newb, so, had it worked (simply providing my Flutter app with the Google Apps Script url), is the simplest solution for the app to get the json data it needs. But, as I mentioned, it is not that simple. So my question is: whats the next simplest way for my Flutter app to get the json data my Google Apps Script generates?
Thanks for reading.. any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand , your mobile app , generate widgets from json data .

and your script requires permissions to convert google sheets data to json.

If it's so ! you have to know few things **Q/A/H** (Question/Answer/How):

Q1-How can you obtain permission to access the json data ?

A1-Google sheets provide you with api_key or OAuth 2.0 token which is normally found in your script because you've been able to generate json data through **web** so you can in **flutter**.

H1-http calls through your flutter mobile app with correct headers / body , so you can use your script and consume data.

Finally it's up to you to chose the best option that fits within your app.

Web -> Script -> Google sheets -> convert -> json

Mobile <-> GetRequest(http) -> json.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok. So, i have api credentials for the script and api credentials for the google sheet. I guess i just need to know how to use those credentials within my flutter/dart code to make the authenticated request. can you provide or point me to some example code? Might this work?: 'class HttpService {
  final String postsUrl = "HTTPSGSCRIPTURL";

  Future<List<Post>> getMenuItems() async {
    Response res = await get(postsUrl, headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "I'M NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE"});'

Comment: authorizationHeader : 'your token' , you have to put your access token there

Comment: for reasons i cant quite explain, @iulius answer here  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634258/share-a-google-app-script-to-other-users-permission-requested-authorize-scri) appears to have worked for me. although i won't know what other things i'd been frantically trying, if any, contributed, until i try recreating my project in production environment.